# How to use an existing Apple ID to download free apps from App Store without using Credit Card?

Tags: mac-appstore, apple-id

I have an Apple ID which I had registered years back (when I had bought my Ipod Shuffle). I wanted to use the same Apple ID to download apps on my newly purchased MBP - but whenever I try to login with that Apple ID, it tells me "This ID hasn't been used with Itunes", and proceeds to let me "Review" it. In the last step, I'm asked to furnish credit card information, which I don't want to, since all I want to do is to be able to download free apps !!

So, do I have to register a second Apple ID just for downloading free apps ??

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. +1 for a good question!

Comment: Hrm... You shouldn't need to furnish credit card info to download freebies and podcasts. Strange that there's no obvious way around it. I'll be the difference in process between setting up a new Apple ID and using an old one is where this gets confused on Apple's end.

Comment: I think they want a credit-card to verify which country you're in, and verify your identity. However, using iTunes, last time I checked, you can set your account to have no card, PayPal, etc. So, perhaps that's worth a try.

Comment: The mac app store is a little less featured (and forgiving) for free users. I would try to use that account from an iOS device or contact billing support to make sure it's not a glitch they could assist with. Having two ID is hard in the long run, but you don't have any purchases on this old ID so you might just start fresh if you prefer...

Comment: I believe I've seen this before and you simply "cancel" or "continue" or "next" or something - basically just skip it. They aren't' demanding you fill it out, juts asking you to review it in the hopes that you will enter a credit card - you shouldn't need to create a new account.

Comment: What is the reason for this difficuly?  I guess: if one can create AppleIDs without proper identification, then some unscrupulous app developers may flood the app reviews with postive reviews of their own apps and negative reviews of their competition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to create a new account. You can do this from your computer or from your iDevice.

You have to create it from the App Store, not the iTunes store.

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2534

Comment: It still asks for credit card information, without the "None" option.

Answer (score 3):

As I commented - try setting your payment type to None in iTunes[image: Payment Types]

Open iTunes, and go to the iTunes Store, then click on your account on the top right. It'll take you to your account page where you can change your type.

Comment: I don't see the "None" option when I use the existing account, that's the problem !!

Comment: @shan23, it might be that initially, you will have to re-enter your CC details as it asks for verification purposes. After you have verified your account, try the steps above. I have just confirmed that there does exist a "None" button (but my account's CC is verified). Also of note, I do not have the PayPal option (perhaps it's not available in Canada).

Comment: I can confirm that "None" is not an option (at least not here in the USA).

Comment: Sadly, this won't work with a pre-existing Apple ID as you can only create a new account and choose none. There is hope that by attempting to redeem a gift card, you can avoid tying a credit card with an existing account to get it to work on the Mac App Store.

Comment: None will be an option after selected Paypal and then cancelling the Paypal login, http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/139634/44901 (might have to change country to USA temporarily)

Answer (score 3):

For those still having this issue (like I did) Select the "Redeem a code or gift" option then sign in again. Once it gives the line to input the code, the option to select "None" shows up.

Comment: Are you saying that you were able to reuse an existing Apple ID and not enter a credit card by going through the gift/giftcard redemption process without needing either a gifted app, a gift card or a valid CC?

Comment: Thank you so. Much tried everything else, but this worked.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem: an existing Apple ID I made couldn't be used for downloading free apps in the App Store without entering credit card information. But here's the steps I used to free up the old account and make a new one:

1. Go to [appleid.apple.com](http://appleid.apple.com) and sign in using the existing ID.
2. Update your email address to another email address of yours. This will also change your Apple ID to that email address.
3. Verify the account using the email.
4. In iTunes, try to download a free app, and when it asks you to sign in, choose the `Create Apple ID` button.
5. Create a new Apple ID using the old, original email you removed from your Apple ID in step 2.
6. Choose `none` while entering other basic info (name, address, etc) and voila, you can download free apps using the same Apple ID.

But if you had used that first Apple ID to make purchases on your iPod shuffle, they wont appear.

I just use this trick because I wanted to download free apps using that particular email address as my Apple ID (while not entering my billing information).

Answer (score 1):

1. Go into iTunes and make sure you are NOT SIGNED IN.
2. Go to the App Store and click "Redeem"
3. When it asks you to review your account details, just click the "Review" button
4. After agreeing to the terms, there should be a "None" button under payment details!